# Merge statement with a conditional INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I noticed in my merge statement that there are rows in the source table with a `PackageId` of `0`. Those records should not be inserted into the destination table. So I'd like to have this condition on my INSERT.

```
MERGE MyTargetTable AS TARGET
USING MySourceTable AS SOURCE
ON (SOURCE.orderidHash = TARGET.Id)
WHEN MATCHED AND (TARGET.CustomerId <> SOURCE.CustomerId
    OR TARGET.PackageId <> SOURCE.packageid
    OR TARGET.TypeId <> SOURCE.ordertypeid
    OR TARGET.Created <> SOURCE.Created
    OR TARGET.Updated <> SOURCE.Changed)
THEN
UPDATE SET TARGET.CustomerId = SOURCE.customeridHash,
     TARGET.PackageId = SOURCE.packageid,
     TARGET.TypeId = SOURCE.ordertypeid,
     TARGET.Created = SOURCE.Created,
     TARGET.Updated = SOURCE.Changed
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
INSERT (
    Id, 
    CustomerId, 
    PackageId,
    TypeId,
    Created, 
    Updated
)
VALUES (
    SOURCE.orderidHash,
    SOURCE.customeridHash,
    SOURCE.packageid,
    SOURCE.ordertypeid,
    SOURCE.Created,
    SOURCE.changed
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

Where in the above statement should I have `WHERE PackageId <> 0`? When I put the condition after `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` I get the error message:

> The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_MyTargetTable_DimCustomer". The conflict occurred in database MyDatabase, table DimCustomer, column Id.

`MyTargetTable.CustomerId` is a FK to `DimCustomer.Id`.

Comment: Limiting the insert to less rows can't possibly fire a foreign key error. You have another problem here. Post the full error message and you will see which FK is failing.

Comment: Have you tried with separate statements? That is my advice to anyone who comes across any issues with `MERGE` (never mind the ones you don't know about yet). See [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)...

Comment: @EzLo I updated the error message. Apparently, there's a foreign key conflict with the table `DimCustomer`.

Answer (score 1):

just change the

```
USING MySourceTable AS SOURCE
to
using (select * from MySourceTable where  PackageId <> 0) as Source
```

Comment: This generates the same error. Apparently, there's a foreign key conflict with the table `DimCustomer`.

Comment: Apparently, the `DimCustomer` table was not updated with new data and that caused the foreign key conflict.

Comment: Since your point also helped with the merge, feel free to update the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Probably the MyTargetTable has a fk relationship to dimcustomer. You would first have to update dimcustor with all the new customer IDs then do the merge. I think that the update TARGET.CustomerId = SOURCE.customeridHash,is probably a mistake. You use this column to get a match and I would not update it. Is target.id and target.customerid unique columns?